# I need to avoid conflict during writing a dictionary into a .json file using asyncio

Tags: python, json, python-asyncio, aiogram

```
async def load_abit_class(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
async with state.proxy() as abit_data:
    abit_data['class'] = int(message.text)
async with open('''D:/Code/data.json''', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(abit_data, file)
await state.finish()
```

That's my code. I am trying to make a tg bot, and I need to write the abit_data dictionary to data.json. But my bot is going to be used by many people and that's so I have to someway write that data avoiding saving conflicts, which can be caused by two people, using the bot at the same moment. I tried to use async but I got traceback:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-31' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\venv_2\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=AttributeError('__aenter__')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\venv_2\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\venv_2\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\venv_2\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\venv_2\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\venv_2\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\handlers\General.py", line 77, in load_abit_class
    async with open('''D:/Code/data.json''', 'w') as file:
AttributeError: __aenter__
```

Help, please!

Comment: asyncio used cooperative multitasking, not true parallelism. Only one task is running at a time so as long as you don’t open the file, yield control back to the event loop, and then overwrite the file, you shouldn’t have to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following code to write data to a Json file:

```
import aiofiles
async with aiofiles.open('D:/Code/data.json', 'w') as file:
    await file.write(json.dumps(abit_data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: Can you explain how and why your code works?